# Replacing the values in a column depending on a match condition using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[Test_File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ut8TYnapZi-tMBgBswTxN8demyqjQ9kQ)I am trying to replace the values in a column with a specific condition:
IF(C37808=$Q$1,D37808,0); So I have copied the filtered column D(D31924:D37908) and pasted it another column F. My goal is to replace the corresponding values of Column F based on the IF-ELSE condition mentioned above.

The first challenge was locating the range of Column C & D because they're are dynamic meaning the first value of Column C or D could start from row number 1 or row number 100 based on a filtered criteria. I have figured out a way to locate that dynamic range so no issue there. Now when I try to replace the values in the corresponding cells of Column F, I see that it pastes only one value. Sharing the code segment below:

```
Sub Replacement()
        Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
        Dim v

        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 3).Select
        End With

        Set rng1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)) 'Finding the range of column C from the filtered region
        rng1.Copy
        v = WorksheetFunction.Mode(rng1) 'finding the mode/highest occuring number in rng1

        Range("Q1").Value = v 'storing if for comparison purpose later

    'Navigating to column F    
        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 3).Select
        End With

        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial 'pasting the copied column C into column F

        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 6).Select
        End With

        Set rng2 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))  'storing the column F's range for replacing

        With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 4).Select
        End With

        Set rng3 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))  'storing the column D's range for using in Column F
        'Looping through each element of column F now and matching against my condition
            For Each z1 In rng2
                If z1.Value = v Then
                    z1.Value = rng3.Value 'expectation is to implement the formula :IF(C37808=$Q$1,D37808,0)
                    Else: z1.Value = 0
                End If
        Next z1
    End Sub
```

After executing the code, I get the only 1st value of column D in all the cells of column F. I would really appreciate if someone can help me fix this issue. Attached is the screenshot of the result.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plj2L.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented and re-worked your code. Now it looks like this.

```
Sub Replacement()

    Dim RngC As Range                       ' Range is in column C
    Dim RngF As Range                       ' use descriptive names
    Dim RngD As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim v As Variant


    ' don't Select anything
'    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
'        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 3).Select
'    End With

    ' the next line will produce an error if no filter is set
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RngC = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 3)
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "Please specify filter criteria", vbCritical, "Can't Proceed"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    Set RngC = Range(RngC, RngC.End(xlDown)) 'Finding the range of column C from the filtered region
    v = WorksheetFunction.Mode(RngC) 'finding the mode/highest occuring number in RngC
    ' no need to write v to the sheet
'    Range("Q1").Value = v 'storing if for comparison purpose later


    'Navigating to column F         ' don't "navigate". Just address
'    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
        ' this is the first cell of RngC
'            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 3).Select
'    End With
'    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial 'pasting the copied column C into column F
    RngC.Copy Destination:=RngC.Cells(1).Offset(0, 3)

    ' don't Select anything!
'    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
'            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 6).Select
'    End With

    Set RngF = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 6)
    ' as an alternative you might specify:-
    ' Set RngF = RngC.Offset(0, 3)
    Set RngF = Range(RngF, RngF.End(xlDown))  'storing the column F's range for replacing

'    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range
'            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 4).Select
'    End With
'    Set RngD = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))  'storing the column D's range for using in Column F
    Set RngD = RngC.Offset(0, 1)



    ' Looping through each element of column F now and matching against my condition
    For Each Cell In RngF
        With Cell
            If .Value = v Then
                ' your line always inserts RngD.Value.
                ' Since RngD is an array but the cell can only take one value
                ' VBA inserts the first value of the array.
                ' z1.Value = RngD.Value 'expectation is to implement the formula :IF(C37808=$Q$1,D37808,0)
                .Value = RngD.Cells(.Row).Value
            Else
                .Value = 0
            End If
        End With
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

It pastes different values now but seems to select them from the wrong rows. The reason is the method by which you set ranges. I don't believe it works as you expect and I can't test it because I don't have data. Two facts:-

1. A range defined as starting from any cell (such as *ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2)(1, 3)*) and ending at the last used cell, will include both visible and invisible cells.
2. The index number of the cells in your ranges aren't aligned with the row numbers of the worksheet.

The task actually is very simple. Just loop through all cells in column F and if an examination meets certain criteria copy the value from column D in the same row. The row number is never in question if handled in this way. So, if my solution doesn't copy from the correct row I suggest you redesign the loop.

Comment: Hi Variatus,

Thank you very much for the response. The code is much cleaner now. I tested it but I have observed two things:

1st: When it's pasting column C into column F, it's skipping two cells in column F.
Filtered range of column C is>$C$31924:$C$37808.
But Filtered range of Column F is> $F$31924:$F$37806 (after being pasted from column C)

2nd: When it's replacing the cell values in column F based on the matched condition, it's pasting the values of something else. Technically, the values in the column F should be exactly the same as the values in Column D. Please check.

Comment: Also not all the values are being replaced in Column F. Seems like it's not filling up many cells in column F. The test file link is:
[Test_File_Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ut8TYnapZi-tMBgBswTxN8demyqjQ9kQ)

Comment: It's the problem I detailed in my answer, Imtiaz. Sheet rows and range rows don't match. Use another (sheet row based) construct for the loop. Note that I can't access Google.

Comment: Hi Variatus,
Thanks for your input. I have implemented another solution to avoid looping through the columns. Once I determined the mode of column C, I simply filtered Column C based on the calculated mode. Then I just took the maximum value from the corresponding column F associated with that mode number. The execution time has been reduced by a bit and it gives me what I want. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Great! If my answer enabled you to find a solution it did what it was designed to do. Please mark it as Selected.